# Own space for position fixed?

Tags: html, css

I would like create same as on stackoverflow - orange comunnicates, but i have problem with css. I dont know how to other page dont cover with messages. On stackoverflow orange messages have own space on the page (same as if messages == 1 or messages == 5) - how can i make it?

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="message">one
        <br />
        two
        <br />
        three
    </div>
    <div class="logo">AAAA</div>
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div class="home">
    <div class="message">one

    </div>
    <div class="logo">BBB</div>
</div>

.home {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f4f28d;
}

.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 80px;
}

.message {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: fixed;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JzUsG/

EDIT: 
.message must be fixed - i want look this also if page is scrolling

http://jsfiddle.net/VnbZf/1/

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Do you want the orange bar not to cover the rest of the page? Like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/VnbZf/)**?

Comment: yes, but .messages must be always on screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fix the position at 0,0 and then add some margin on the top of the page calculated from the height of each message multiplied by the number of messages:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8uBS/

If you want something more "dynamic" without calculation on the server side you can calculate the height of the messages with javascript and then inject that into the appropriate position:

http://jsfiddle.net/kGXnZ/

Comment: Your Javascript solution is better than mine :)

Comment: I've added the ability to close the messages and update that offset dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/kGXnZ/5 (it also falls back gracefully if JS is disabled)

Answer (score 4):

Being in (I think) a similar situation that was to fix a first div (like a navigation bar) avoiding to let the next div to partially (in my case, partially) hide beneath the first div, I found this solution:
I set the first div as "position: sticky; top: 0px" In this way the first div acts as fixed to the top (my intention) but the space remains "occupied".
Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If the message must be fixed on top of the page, I'm afraid the only solution is to use `position: relative;` and use some Javascript to move the bar when page is scrolled. **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gkLsd/)** you can see a Mootools example, but you can achieve the same result with jQuery or using pure Javascript.

If you want to avoid Javascript, you have to know how much your message bar is tall before the page renders. So, let's say the bar is 60px tall, you can place the bar **outside** the home `<div>` and apply `padding-top: 60px;` (or `margin-top: 60px;`) the the `div.home`. You can see the result **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KJX2e/)**.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to lorenzo-s answer. I was trying to accomplish something similar and position relative with a handler for `$( window ).scroll()` that positioned the element was the way to go. The problem with solutions that suggest padding to the height of the fixed element is that often the actual height is not known to begin with or at load time such as when the element is a div that contains image elements or elements that will be dynamically added. The problem with solutions that suggest cloning are that you have to be careful to change ids and sometimes you don't want the same class names when they are used as selectors, so you end up walking the dom changing ids and classes and your css gets cluttered with aliases.  So, for accomplishing the same as `position:fixed`, while still taking up the original space in the document (flow):

1. `position: relative`. Set the position of the element to move with the page to relative.
2. `$( window ).scroll() handler`. Implement a handler for window.scroll.
3. Calculate and move the element as the page scrolls inside the scroll handler. Something like:

   ```
   $element
       .stop()
       .animate( { 'top': distance }, { "duration": 500, "easing": "easeInOutQuart" } );
   ```